# Testing a GeoLocation request

Tags: akamai

We are using akamai's `X-Akamai-Edgescape` in order to detect the territory of the user making the request. If it does not match users home territory, then we deny the request.

Our integration tests are using a locally hosted deployment of akamai proxy. Whenever they add `X-Akamai-Edgescape` with any custom territory like `XX`, the proxy overrides the header with its own value of the header.

Eg. From integration tests, we send `X-Akamai-Edgescape=region_code=MA,dma=506,pmsa=1120,country_code=DE`

and akamai overrides it to 
`X-Akamai-Edgescape:georegion=1,country_code=GB,region_code=EN`

Is there a way to disable this overriding behavior on akamai proxy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear from your question what technology you're using to inject these headers in the client request. Are you running a local test version of the Akamai server, or a local version of the [EdgeScape](https://community.akamai.com/community/web-performance/blog/2016/03/16/content-targeting-a-basic-introduction) database?

In either case, the headers that get sent to the client or to the origin server can be modified in your delivery configuration. If you're using Property Manager (the default tool for all current delivery products), you can create a new behavior that will pass the header through.

Start by choosing the appropriate header behavior you're trying to control.
[image: property manager behavior selection]

Then simply update the behavior to do what you're looking for. In this example, I'm telling the delivery configuration to pass the `X-Akamai-EdgeScape` header through to the origin.
[image: animated adjustment of the behavior]